# Creating multiple dataframe in faster way with function?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, function, iteration, user-defined-functions

I need to create multiple dataframe (let say 30 dataframe) in faster way rather manually create one-by-one dataframe. anyone has answer or reference links? Thank you in advance

```
def dvd(y):
    df = port_type.where(port_type['DATE']==y).dropna()
    return df

df_0 = dvd(date_0)
df_1 = dvd(date_1)
df_2 = dvd(date_2)
df_3 = dvd(date_3)
df_4 = dvd(date_4)
df_5 = dvd(date_5)
```

Comment: Don't. Use a list or dictionary as container: `dvds = [dvd(date) for date in dates]` or `dvds = {date: dvd(date) for date in dates}`

Comment: Ok mozway , i understand so i just create list of dates = [date[0],date[1],date[2]]. Thanks mozway

Comment: in this case `dates = date[:3]`, if `date` is already a list, no?

Comment: it is already a list, mozway, edit my first comment so no need to create list of dates again. am i correct ?

Comment: just like this dvds = [dvd(date) for date in date]

Comment: Yes, **but** then you should change the looping variable to avoid conflict: `dvds = [dvd(x) for x in date]`. Or `dvds = list(map(dvd, date))`

Comment: ok understand, thanks mozway ,it is really very helpful answer.